# Recover database from backed up xampp folder

Tags: xampp

I had a database in xampp, but my laptop broke. I was able to recover the hard drive, which has the xampp folder in it.

Now, on my new laptop, I would like to be able to use the same database, how do I do this?

I don't know how to run the old xampp from the hard drive, so all I'm left with are the files but I don't know which ones I need to copy.

Answer (score 0):

After a good amount of trial and error, I came up with a solution: zipping and unzipping the whole xampp folder in the new directory.

Even though this works, if someone has a more elegant solution to this I'll be more than willing to hear about it!